# How to Extract one images from bunch of image(Image Pack)?

Tags: css, html, image

I have seen many site displaying one image from the image pack . How can we do that .

For example: http://www.flipkart.com/prod/images/new-vd-sprite-b2a14956.png

I want to extract the cross sign from this image.

I have a rough idea that it can't be done by  , we have to use CSS for it.
Does anyone have better idea about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This technique is known as **CSS sprite**.

### HTML

```
<span class="sprite contact"></span>
<span class="sprite store"></span>
```

CSS

```
span.sprite {
    height: 30px;
    width: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: burlywood;
    background-image: url('http://www.flipkart.com/prod/images/new-vd-sprite-b2a14956.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
span.contact {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
span.store {
    background-position: 0 -80px;
}
```

More resources:

- http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29#Sprites_by_CSS